# How to choose the best strategy to configure role-based authorization using AWS Cognito User pools?

Tags: graphql, authorization, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I'm building an Angular 11 app with AWS Amplify as the backend which uses Appsync, dynamodb and a managed GraphQL API. I'm using the cognito user pools to authenticate. Authentication works neatly, but I am really confused about how to go about doing role-based authorization. I haven't done this using cognito before but I have a strategy in mind that should theoretically work out. I would like advice on if there is a better way to do this:-

**Requirements:-**

The app will be used by members of organisations that we are partnering with. Every member will be tied to an organisation. So organisations have their own table and so do members. Members of an organisation can only access content related to their organisation. So right after authentication, the client app has to get the id of the organisation the current user belongs to and also the role they play in that organisation to show/hide UI resources and filter data. Which UI resources they can access depends on the role they play in that organisation and of course the data they see there has to be restricted to what is related to their organisation.

This is a controlled beta release of our application, so Cognito user pools uses email and password to login. No other login option is provided for the sake of keeping things simple. User sign up is not possible. Only admins can add new users for now.

**How I plan to do this:-**

1. Cognito API is integrated to the client and the admin will add the
   new members from the client UI and the client will add them to the
   cognito user pool via the Cognito API
2. While adding the new members, the admin will specify which
   organisation they belong to and what role they play in it. But the
   organisation and role are not details that are stored within the
   user pools. There is a separate dynamodb table called "members"
   which stores these information because these can change frequently
   and need to be flexible.
3. Additions made to the Cognito user pool trigger a lambda function
   that automatically syncronizes the "members" table in the amplify
   backend in a dynamoDB table with the new additions to the user pool.
4. So when the admin adds a new user from the client UI, they
   fill out a form with the email ID, name, organisation and role of
   the new user, and the client UI will create that user with the name
   and email ID in the user pool via the cognito API. Once that request
   returns the user's ID (remember it will also trigger the creation of
   a record in the member's table via the lambda funciton), we create a
   mutation to the member's table adding the organisation and the role to the user's record in the member table.
5. Cognito user pool only has the email ID, name and user ID and
   nothing else, all other information is stored in the members table,
   which also has the ID, and name (for human reference) but not the
   Email ID. We will not be holding the same information in
   these two tables to avoid redundancy.
6. Updates to the email ID can be made by individual users via the
   client app which will do it in the cognito user pool via the cognito
   API. And no updates need to be made to the member table after email
   update since the member table doesn't have the email ID. All other
   member details can be made to the members table via the client app.
7. When the user logs in, as soon as the cognito UI authenticates the
   user and sends over the email ID and user id, we fetch the member
   details from the member table using the user ID and get details such as their name,
   organisation they belong to and their role. And using the
   information on their role, we can restrict UI resources using flags
   in the UI Code. To achieve this, there will be a separate table that
   will let the admin user modify access to the UI resources for each
   role. So we'll need to fetch the role and the associated UI tags
   right after authentication as well.
8. And as for how data is filtered as per the organisation, I am not
   sure yet, but I would like to use an authorizer that will be
   specified using a function in the graphql schema itself, that will
   get the organisation ID with each request and use that to filter the
   data before returning to the client.

Not sure if this process is solid, but this is what I was able to fathom. Please let me know if I am doing this in a sensible way or if there are better ways to achieve what I am doing.

Comment: I'm trying to understand use-case, and came up with some queries. Can user be part of multiple organizations? Do you have created one user-pool OR separate user-pool per organization? In DynamoDB's members table, you would be storing role meta-data. Hence, would it be a JSON document to define role level permission?

Comment: One user can only be part of only one organization. It's one user pool only. There will be different user groups within that userpool that indicate their role in their organisation. At the moment I am just thinking of using permissions tied to each group name as a JSON object in a separate dynamoDB table so that I can change easily from within the client UI. And of course whenever the user authenticates, it will fetch the role-based permissions from there as part of the standard authentication flow. I can specify the data restrictions for each group in the Amplify graphql schema itself.

Comment: I suppose Cognito's different user groups (each group will have separate IAM roles to define permission on resources) mapped to different user roles should be fine. Moreover, as user would be only in one group, you wouldn't have to worry about group precedence. Do you really need DynamoDB table to store JSON of permissions?

Comment: Good question. I was thinking of doing that only because I don't know how to configure complex permissions any other way using cognito. Hence the reason for posting this question. Is it possible to setup a list of UI resources that each group should be allowed to access within the IAM role it is attached to? How?

Sorry if this is a simple question, but the documentation is kinda scattered and doesn't offer a streamlined introduction to a newbie like me.

Comment: If you want to define AWS resource level permissions (such as S3, RDS etc.) for user group than Cognito group's IAM policy should be sufficient. You can generate and test policy with help of policy generator tool https://awspolicygen.s3.amazonaws.com/policygen.html     However, if you want to have fine grained access control on other things (non AWS resources) than DynamoDB's table would be worth to store it.